# Can I use SQL Triggers to track changes from C# Console App on Database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers, sqldependency

I'm a newbie on using SQL Triggers, All I've done that I created an after-update trigger, that whenever I write a SQL update query it shows me the change, but I need to know If I have a console app that runs similar update on the table, would the trigger be useful and show me the change? if possible how to display such change? if not, is SQLDependency a good C# alternative to triggers?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes the trigger WILL be useful for any program or method of updating.

If the trigger is working from within SQL Management Studio then it shouldn't matter where you run the query from... the trigger should execute. You should be able to run you C# query and it have the same effect